# Unusual ActiveRecord Association Chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations

I am trying to figure out the right way to chain my associations effeciently. I basically have the following hierarchy:

School > Course > Lecture > Attachment

Users can have many of any of these, which indicates not that they own them but rather that they are enrolled in or have access to them. We then use cancan for authorization.

My challenge is that users can be enrolled in a school and then separately enroll in each course, OR they can be enrolled in a "school-wide" package that gives them access to all courses. Before the addition of the latter, our user model includes the following:

```
belongs_to :school
has_many :active_sales, -> { where active: true }, class_name: "Sale"
has_many :courses, through: :active_sales, source: :sale
has_many :lectures, through: :courses
has_many :attachments, through: :lectures
```

In trying to add the school-wide sales (sales is polymorphic as "enrollable" with both courses and schools), I can't figure out how to chain the associations together properly. Basically, it's like the chain forks and then rejoins itself. It would be nice if I could do something like

```
has_many :courses, through: :active_sales, source: :sale, -> {where (id: active_sale.enrollable_id && active_sale.enrollable_type: 'Course') || (school_id: active_sale.enrollable_id && active_sale.enrollable_type: 'School') }
```

...but I'm pretty sure the where method doesn't take associations and not clear if it takes strung together conditions either. I tried messing with association extensions, but was having trouble there too.

Is there a best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla AtiveRecord can be hard to use in case of complex queries unless you write the SQL statement yourself. The only way to do an OR statement would be to write the whole SQL statement as a string and use it as the where clause.

But you could also use Arel to shape your query instead.

https://github.com/rails/arel

In your case, I think it would make your code cleaner if you created a scope for the active_sales_courses or a class method, instead of trying to put everything in an `has_many` statement.

```
def self.active_sales_courses
  courses = Arel::Table.new(:courses)
  active_sales = Arel::Table.new(:active_sales)
  query = courses.joins(active_sales).on(courses[:id].eq(active_sales[:enrollable_id])).
    where((courses[:id].eq(active_sales[:enrollable_id]).
      and(active_sales[:enrollable_type].eq('Course'))).
    or(courses[:school_id].eq(active_sales[:enrollable_id]).
      and(active_sales[:enrollable_type].eq('School'))))
  query.to_sql
end
```

I can't guarantee this code works as I have no way of testing it but it is provided as an indication.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm a bit of a rails dinosaur (jumping into 4 after being away for years); AREL is one of the things I've been meaning to familiarize myself with -- I'll get around to it now. To clarify regarding using a raw SQL query, wouldn't that bypass the lazy loading chaining and make extra queries?

Comment: Well where and includes should deal with that themselves. I must admit I'm not sure at all. I guess you can give it a try to see if the behaviour changes. But Arel should keep the lazy loading as expected.